# Required Field Validator not working ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I am trying to implement a required field validator on my form so that when I click my 'send' button it only works if all of the required fields have a value. Right now though even if I set up a RequiredFieldValidator and click send the function still fires and is not stopped. This is my code as of now:

**Default.aspx**

```html
   <form action="./Default.aspx" method="post" runat="server">
        <div id="tabs" style="border:none" class="">
            <br />
            <br />
            <button class="backBtn" type="button" name="goBackBtn" onclick="backBtnClicked()"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/back-arrow/win8/1600"></button>
            <h1 class="title">Create NetEvent</h1>

            <br />

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Sender Info</legend>
                <div class="row">
                  <label class="senderInfoUniversal senderInfoLabel">Username:</label>
                  <input class="senderInfoUniversal senderInfoInput" type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormName" readonly="readonly"/>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <label class="senderInfoUniversal senderInfoLabel">Email:</label>
                  <input class="senderInfoUniversal senderInfoInput" type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormEmail" readonly="readonly"/>                  
                </div>  
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="senderInfoUniversal senderInfoInputExtra">*Sender email used when sending out NetEvent</label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <br />

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Type of Event</legend>
                <div class="row">
                    <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group col-md-12">
                        <label runat="server" id="serviceDisruptionLabel" class="btn btn-default" for="serviceDisruptionBtn" onclick="displayServiceDisruptionForm()">Service Disruption
                            <input class="labelInput" id="serviceDisruptionBtn" type="radio" required="required"/>
                        </label>
                        <label runat="server" id="plannedOutageLabel" class="btn btn-default" for="plannedOutageBtn" onclick="displayPlannedOutageForm()">Planned Outage
                            <input class="labelInput" id="plannedOutageBtn" type="radio"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <br /> 

            <fieldset>
                <legend>NetEvent Information</legend>

                <div id="serviceDisruptionForm" hidden="hidden">
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Subject Line
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <asp:TextBox type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormSubjectLineSD" class="userInfo form-control customFormElement" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                                runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="eventFormSubjectLineSD" 
                                ErrorMessage="THIS DID NOT WORK">
                            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Summary
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <textarea type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormSummarySD" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"/>   
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Resources Affected
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <select type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormResourcesAffectedSD" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name" clientIdMode="static">
                                <option style="display:none;"></option>
                            </select>
                            <textarea runat="server" id="eventFormResourcesAffectedOtherSD" clientIdMode="static"></textarea>
                            <textarea runat="server" id="resourcesOtherRowSD" hidden="hidden" clientIdMode="static"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> People Affected
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <textarea type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormPeopleAffectedSD" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Work Around
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <textarea type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormWorkAroundSD" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Start Time
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormStartTimeSD" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name" clientIdMode="static"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Estimated Time of Resolution
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col">
                                <label id="unknownTextSD" for="eventFormTimeCheckBoxSD">Unknown</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="eventFormTimeCheckBoxSD" clientIdMode="static"/>  
                            </div>                                                  
                            <input type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormEstimatedTimeOfResolutionSD" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name" clientIdMode="static"/>                       
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label id="draftLabelSD" class="userInfo">Save as Draft</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="eventFormDraftCheckBoxSD" clientIdMode="static"/>
                            <textarea runat="server" id="eventFormDraftEmailInputSD" clientIdMode="static" hidden="hidden" 
                                placeholder="Type in the emails you would like the draft to be set to, seperated by a comma"/>        
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div id="plannedOutageForm" hidden="hidden">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Subject Line
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormSubjectLinePO" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Summary
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <textarea type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormSummaryPO" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Resources Being Changed
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <select type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormResourcesBeingChangedPO" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name" clientIdMode="static">
                                <option style="display:none;"></option>
                            </select>
                            <textarea runat="server" id="eventFormResourcesBeingChangedOtherPO" clientIdMode="static"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Change Benefits
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <textarea type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormChangeBenefitsPO" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Impact on End Users
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <textarea type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormImpactOnEndUsersPO" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Proposed Start Date/Time
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormProposedStartDatePO" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="userInfo"> Proposed End Date/Time
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" runat="server" id="eventFormProposedEndDatePO" class="userInfo form-control" 
                                title="Invalid Subject Name"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label id="draftLabelPO" class="userInfo">Save as Draft</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="eventFormDraftCheckBoxPO" clientIdMode="static"/>
                            <textarea runat="server" id="eventFormDraftEmailInputPO" clientIdMode="static" hidden="hidden" 
                                placeholder="Type in the emails you would like the draft to be set to, seperated by a comma"/>        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>    
            
            <br />                

            <asp:Button ID="eventFormSubmitBtn" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClientClick="setValidators()" OnClick="eventFormSubmitBtn_Clicked"/>

            <asp:HiddenField ID="typeHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Also all of this is nested within a form running on the server.

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
 // Buttin Submit Methods
    protected void eventFormSubmitBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveData();
        goBackToStartPage();
    }
```

So right now even if the form has empty fields, clicking the button still sends me to another page. Does it have something to do with my Type of event field set, where I am toggling between a service disruption or planned outage? I want to make it so when the Service disruption is selected the send button pressed does not work unless required fields have a value and same for when planned outage is selected.

[image]

Comment: You need to do `if (Page.IsValid)`

Comment: This caused the validator to throw but after I click send it makes neither of the 'Type of Event' selectors active and hides the form how should i tackle that

Comment: Also the validator fires no matter which item I have selected I want it to only validator for the currently selected form

Comment: Those radios are not runat server, if you make them runat server the ViewState will help you out.

Comment: Also how do I disable postback on the button since I am assuming that is what is making the page reload every time I click send

Comment: return false on the client side function doesn't work

Comment: do you have a script manager on the page?